# Irregular point cloud from voxels

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

My objective is to partition my point cloud (derived from TLSs) to voxels where the user has to define side length of voxels. Once voxels are created, I have to select only one point lying in the voxel that satisfies a certain condition. So far, I programmed this objective but I have a small problem. In some parts of the point cloud the point density is becoming higher as shown in following figure(denser area marked with red polygon):

[image]

I think this is a result of adjacent voxels in Z direction which is perpendicular to XY plane. Could you please help me about this issue?

Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    //pcd'ye dönüştürülen dosyanın okunması
    pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ>("input/yeni_proje_V2_ENTIRE_CLOUD_with_SEMI_DIAGONAL - Cloud.pcd", *cloud);
    //voxel boyutu (metre)
    float resolution = 0.02f;
    //voxel index merkez ve içindeki noktalar
    FILE *Dosya = fopen("output/yeni_proje_V2_ENTIRE_VOXELS_INDEXES_2cm_SEMI_DIAGONAL_ROTATED.xyz", "w+");
    //hata elipsoidlerini içeren dosya
    FILE* Dosya2 = fopen("input/yeni_proje_V2_ENTIRE_CLOUD_with_SEMI_DIAGONAL - ROTATED.xyz", "r");
    //elipsoidi en küçük olan noktalar
    FILE *Dosya3 = fopen("output/yeni_proje_V2_2cm_selected_ONLY_COORDS_SEMI_DIAGONAL_ROTATED.xyz", "w+");
    FILE *Dosya4 = fopen("output/yeni_proje_V2_2cm_selected_SEMI_DIAGONAL_ROTATED.xyz", "w+");

    //FILE *Dosya5 = fopen("input/FARO_salon010203_COORDINATES_NORMALS.xyz", "r");
    //FILE *Dosya6 = fopen("output/FARO_salon010203_5cm_selected_COORDINATES_and_NORMALS_SEMI_DIAGONAL.xyz", "w+");


    pcl::octree::OctreePointCloudSearch<pcl::PointXYZ> octree(resolution);
    int index;
    double a, b, c, deer;
    double* r_deer = new double[cloud->points.size()];// hata parametri çekme

    double* normal_x = new double[cloud->points.size()];
    double* normal_y = new double[cloud->points.size()];
    double* normal_z = new double[cloud->points.size()];
    for (index = 0; index < cloud->points.size(); index++)// hata parametri çekme
    {
        fscanf(Dosya2, "%lf %lf %lf %lf", &a, &b, &c, &deer);//4 lü dosya
        r_deer[index] = deer;
        //fscanf(Dosya5, "%lf %lf %lf %lf   %lf %lf", &a, &b, &c, &normal_x[index], &normal_y[index],&normal_z[index]);
    }

    std::cout << normal_x[4] <<" "<<normal_y[4]<<" "<< normal_z[4] << std::endl;
    octree.setInputCloud(cloud);
    octree.addPointsFromInputCloud();
    pcl::PointXYZ searchPoint;
    std::cout << "Voxel sayisi: " << octree.getLeafCount() << std::endl;
    // Neighbors within voxel search
    std::vector<pcl::PointXYZ, Eigen::aligned_allocator<pcl::PointXYZ>> pointGrid;
    octree.getOccupiedVoxelCenters(pointGrid);
    int k = 0;
    int kıyas = 0;
    /*
    int kontrol;
    std::cout << "kontrol satiri girin:" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> kontrol;//kontrol
    kontrol = kontrol - 1;
    */
    for (k = 0; k < octree.getLeafCount(); k++)
    {
    //  if (k == kontrol) std::cout << "Secili merkez" << "(" << pointGrid[k].x << " " << pointGrid[k].y << " " << pointGrid[k].z << ")" << std::endl;//kontrol

        fprintf(Dosya, "%i  %f  %f  %f", k + 1, pointGrid[k].x, pointGrid[k].y, pointGrid[k].z);
        std::vector<int> pointIdxVec;
        double limit = sqrt(3)*resolution;
        limit = limit / 2;
        if (octree.voxelSearch(pointGrid[k], pointIdxVec))
        {
            kıyas = pointIdxVec[0];
            for (size_t i = 0; i < pointIdxVec.size(); ++i)
            {

                if (pointIdxVec.size() - (i + 1) != 0)//Hata elipsoidlerini kıyasla ve en küçüğü ver 
                {
                    if (r_deer[kıyas] > r_deer[pointIdxVec[i + 1]])kıyas = pointIdxVec[i + 1];
                }

                //if (kontrol == k) std::cout << pointIdxVec[i] + 1 << "(" << r_deer[pointIdxVec[i]] << ")" << std::endl; //kontrol

                fprintf(Dosya, "    %i", pointIdxVec[i] + 1);
                if (pcl::euclideanDistance(cloud->points[pointIdxVec[i]], pointGrid[k]) >= limit)
                {
                    std::cout << pointIdxVec[i] << " " << cloud->points[pointIdxVec[i]] << "    Nokta voxelin icinde degil!!! " << std::endl;
                    std::cout << pcl::euclideanDistance(cloud->points[pointIdxVec[i]], pointGrid[k]) << "   Merkezle Mesefe" << std::endl;
                    std::cout << limit << " Olması gereken maksimum mesafe" << std::endl;
                }
            }


            //if (kontrol == k) std::cout << "Minimum:" << kıyas + 1 << "(" << r_deer[kıyas] << ")" << std::endl; //kontrol
            fprintf(Dosya3, "%f %f  %f\n", cloud->points[kıyas].x, cloud->points[kıyas].y, cloud->points[kıyas].z);
            //fprintf(Dosya6, "%f   %f  %f  %f  %f  %f\n", cloud->points[kıyas].x, cloud->points[kıyas].y, cloud->points[kıyas].z, normal_x[kıyas], normal_y[kıyas], normal_z[kıyas]);
            fprintf(Dosya4, "%f %f  %f  %f\n", cloud->points[kıyas].x, cloud->points[kıyas].y, cloud->points[kıyas].z,r_deer[kıyas]);
            fprintf(Dosya, "\n");
        }
    }
    fclose(Dosya);
    fclose(Dosya2);
    fclose(Dosya3);
    fclose(Dosya4);
    //fclose(Dosya5);
    //fclose(Dosya6);

}
```

I am looking forward to hearing from you

Mustafa

Comment: Can you share the code you are using?

Comment: What exactly is the issue you want to solve? Filter out the points that are outside the xy plane you are interested in? Downsize the point cloud so it is uniformly dense?

Comment: Dear David de la Iglesia I editted my question and inserted my code. Dear brad my objective is to select only one point for each voxel and this one point has to satisfy a certain condition. After this selection, the number of points should be equal to number of occupied voxels. And the resulting point cloud should approximately be regular. However, in my case, density at some parts of the resulting point cloud is not regular. The reason is, in the area marked with red polygon there are adjacent voxels in z direction which results in irregularity at density. Can you please help me about it?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are trying to "Voxelize" your data and you want to store in each voxel a custom data structure to satisfy your custom requirements. Here is a general 3D Mapping Framework that let you to store in Voxel your custom data:

https://github.com/m4nh/skimap_ros

You have to create a custom data for you Voxel that is able to store a set of points implementig a custom method:

`voxel.getSatisfactoryPoint(..)`

that hides your business logic and gives back just one point for each voxel.